# Is it possible to import a map from an esri rest server into R as a simple features object?

Tags: r, r-sf

[Here is map](https://data.milwaukee.gov/dataset/street-sweeping/resource/76f71567-f2ed-4737-95a2-414cb385d773) on a pretty standard municipal open data website. It's hosted by ArcGIS rest services. I'd like to import it into R, preferably without downloading it.

Obviously, this doesn't work:

```
sf::st_read("https://data.milwaukee.gov/dataset/street-sweeping/resource/76f71567-f2ed-4737-95a2-414cb385d773")
```

Is there some straightforward way to do this that I'm missing? I tried googling it, of course, but didn't turn up anything useful. I may just lack the correct terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently gdal 2.3 should have an ESRIJSON driver that can read this directly, but I don't have that to hand at the moment. Instead you can use the 2.2 GeoJSON driver once you've constructed an appropriate query string. In this case:

```
 map = st_read('https://maps2.milwaukee.gov/arcgis/rest/services/DPW/DPW_sanitation/MapServer/19/query?returnGeometry=true&where=1=1&outFields=*&f=geojson')
```

The base of that URL is given on the page you referenced - just add the parameters which say to return geometry, return all features, all fields, in geojson format. There's a chance that for large numbers of features the server will only return pages of 20 (or whatever) at a time so bear that in mind. There are other parameters that will let you load 1-20, then 21-30 and so on with several calls.